# Identifying active telnet sessions and their IPs

Tags: linux, command, telnet

Is there any way/command to detect ongoing telnet sessions? I have a linux system which is shared by 3-4 engineers. I want to track which engineer is logged in and from which ip address. Is there any command/log which can provide me above informations?

Comment: Telnet? Uhhh.... that is out-dated and insecure... Use ssh, the logs in /var/log/messages will show the logins at the date/time...Why telnet...?

Comment: @tommieb75: I tried ssh using putty, but I am not getting any messages in /var/log/messages. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is `who` or `w`

Comment: `who -aH` and then `kill PID`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `finger`.